# When I type anything in Textbox then it should fire in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

My requirement is I've Listbox and top of that textbox available. When user comes and search for listBox items then user will type in Textbox.

Here my code is

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onKeyDown="Search()"></asp:TextBox>
```

C# code is

```
public void Search(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string txtOrig = txtSearch.Text;
    var filter = listTypesFilter.Where(c => c.NAME.IndexOf(txtOrig, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);

    listTypes.DataSource = filter;
    listTypes.DataBind();

}
```

I've tried txtSearch_TextChanged event with AutoPostBackTrue and when I type something and click on Tab and it works fine. But Now I need when user Type something in Textbox automatically filter should display.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated and without AutoCompleteExtender

Cheers

Comment: OkKeyDown() is a Client side Event and you are calling it from server side..so obviously it will not fire..

Comment: You should use jquery autofill..

Comment: Is there a reason for not using the AutoCompleteExtender - which is exactly appropriate solution for you needs?

Comment: @J.Starkl AutomcompleteExtender is only display on Textbox but I need to display in Listbox based on search on Textbox

Comment: You need a Ajax method that will be called `onKeyDown` event on the client. From this method you can call a Server method that will return the Filtered list in `JSON` format. Once you get the response back to the client you need to bind that to the List again using JQUERY. You might want to mark your AJAX method as `async=false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you want to filter in the code behind you have to do a postback. For my solution you need jquery. You can try this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="Search" CssClass="txt"></asp:TextBox>
```

I added a css class to the textbox to find it easily with jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.txt').keyup(function () {
            $(this).change();
        });
```

edit: you may consider to use an update panel to "hide" the postback or use only javascript to do the filtering

edit2: a workaround to wait the end of the input

```
    var timeoutReference;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('txt').keypress(function() {
         var _this = $(this); // copy of this object for further usage

         if (timeoutReference) clearTimeout(timeoutReference);
         timeoutReference = setTimeout(function() {
          $('txt').change();
         }, 500);
});
});
```

edit3: the code above should work.

Comment: Thanks Mate..Its working but the issue is when I just Type its loading..May be because of Keyup. I need like once my typing is done ex: Daily then it should show all Daily in the List.

Comment: i found this http://jsfiddle.net/xVBMW/2/ and try to adapt che code to your problem. Hope it helps. Let me know if it does work!

Comment: Its working but when I click mouse then only filter was updating into Listbox.Even I gave timeoutreference to 1000 also. I think When i type "Dai" automatically Listbox should show all Daily records and again if I remove "Dai" from textbox then again it will populate all the records.Almost there please help on this. Really appreciated mate

Comment: Try keyup instead of keypress

Comment: No luck mate.Still I need to release the mouse then updating. I mean to say If the cursor is come out of the text box then absolutely works.

Comment: In the fiddle it is working http://jsfiddle.net/xVBMW/28/
when i delete the event is triggered, give it a try.
Don't know how to fix your problem, is the console giving an error or something?

Comment: Even I can get Alert message David in my code. Even I didn't understand why listbox was not updating until cursor outs from text box

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint in the code behind and see if the method is called and the content of the textbox

Comment: Yeah mate I've debugged. Alert message was popping up but txtSearch_TextChanged event was only fires when I release cursor. That is the problem because its server event.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37337/discussion-between-user1990395-and-davide-lettieri)

Comment: Thanks for resolving the issue and a big ton to David.

Answer (score 0):

`onKeyDown="Search()"` is looking for the `JavaScript` function `Search`.

You'll need a client side function, such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function Search() {
        alert('Searching');
   }
</script>
```

You could use something like [`jQuery autocomplete`](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:textbox id="txtBOX1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtbox1_TextChanged()" AutoPostBack=true/>
```

This should work..
Make sure Auto Post Back is set to true for text box control

Comment: No it doesn't work because txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) has arguments and javascript doesn't have any arguments.

Comment: If you do want to handle this from client side , using jquery call an ajax function that retieves the filtered data

Comment: It is working only when you press Tab button. I need when you type anything in texbox automatically filter the Listbox

Comment: Ok..now i got your requirement. The only way to accomplish this is by using Auto Complete control if you are familiar with ASP.net Ajax control tool kit

Comment: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx..this link would help you

Comment: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_autocomplete_simple.ashx ..this is another example